# Conditional density function of the waiting time of the $m$th event?

Tags: probability, poisson-process

A Poisson process has intensity $\lambda$. Given $X (t) = n$, derive the conditional density function for the waiting time of the $m$th event, provided $m ≤ n$.

---

From my textbook, it looks like waiting times are distributed according to the gamma function. I'm a little unsure of how to get started on this. Is this conditional on $X(t)=n$? The wording of these questions is still a little confusing to me. Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: *Unconditional* waiting times are distributed according to the gamma function, but that does not work for conditional distributions.  For instance if $X(t) = 1$, then the waiting time for that event is of course uniform in $(0, t)$.  If $X(t) = 2$, then the waiting time for the first event is the minimum of two variables uniform in $(0, t)$, while the second event is the maximum of those two variables.  And so on.  Can you generalize?

Comment: Oh. I get what you're saying, but no, I don't know how to generalize that.

Comment: Is there something in your textbook about the beta distribution?